# Spree - customize checkout process - after complete callback is not executing

Tags: spree

hi i have the following lines of code in my order_decorator.rb

```
Spree::Order.state_machine.before_transition :to => :delivery,
                                             :do => :valid_geolocation?

Spree::Order.state_machine.after_transition :to => :complete,
                                             :do => :notify_shops_new_order
```

`valid_geolocation?` gets called before transitioning to `:delivery` but `notify_shops_new_order` is not called after the `complete` state.

I have no clue why. I'm using paypal to do the checkout. I don't know if this could be related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the spree_paypal_express gem, it doesn't use a natural state machine transition to the complete state, and therefore the after complete callback won't be called.  What's worked for me in the past is to chain your call to the `finalize!` method:

```
# in order_decorator.rb
def finalize_with_notify_shops!
  finalize_without_notify_shops!
  notify_shops_new_order
end
alias_method_chain :finalize!, :notify_shops
```